# (Open Source) Log Management for ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, logs, web-services

I am looking for an open-source Log Management (not logging) solution in C#, to use it together with an ASP.NET webservice. I need something that I can upload logs from different services (Apache, etc) to, that will parse them and store them in a database, so that I can report all errors from all systems via a webpage. Something like http://logstash.net/ but in C#, that can be used by just calling methods (instead of having to build a wrapper).

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you look at elmahr? Its not exactly as you describe, but it can log anything that can make a http request to it.

Comment: @Jogai I don't need a logging solution. As I wrote, I was looking for a Log Management System. I want to call methods in C#, not by HTTP requests.